# How to install mechanize for Python 2.7(YES ITS A DUPLICATE)

Tags: python, package

I have named this question exactly the same as a previous question with answers on purpose. Though I imagine that question is answered for people who know what they are doing, it is not answered there for someone like me.

I try to run the setup.py files for mechanize and distribute. I try to follow the site instructions for using the command line and all i get is errors along the lines of 'not a recognized external or internal command operable program or batch file.

Does anyone know of somewhere I can get a tutorial for installing packages in general because this is a common thread for me, The instructions are always succinct and seem easy but almost never work for me ( for any package to be installed without a simple windows exe installer), and I know I can't be the only one.

Please help.

Comment: get setuptools ... then run `pip install mechanize`

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html

Comment: Installation instructions are for people who already know how to install it? The problem sounds like that you're trying to install software to Windows by following instructions written for Unix.

Comment: Could you include some details about your environment, and which instructions you are attempting to follow, and which step is failing?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure python is on your path.  Go to your Python install directory and copy the path.  It should be something similar to C:\Python27.  To check if it is on your path, go to start menu, right click on computer, then click properties.  I am assuming you are using Windows 7.  On the left of this window, click on Advanced System Settings.  Then go to environment variables on the advanced tab.  In the box where it says System Variables, scroll down to the variable called path.  Make sure that C:\Python27 is in that line somewhere.  It may be easier to copy and paste that long string (which can be over 1000 lines long) into a text editor and use a search function.  If it is not in there, paste C:\Python27 into the long string.  Make sure the ending of the previous directory ends with a `;` or the path will not work.  You may want to add it to the front of the variable value because sometimes different variables use the same characters.  That is what I had to do to get pip working because it was giving me some strange message, but it was still on my path.  Hope this helps.

EDIT:  Make sure you hit ok on all three open windows to make sure the changes take place.  Also, you have to restart command prompt for the changes to take place.  May even have to restart the machine, but I doubt it.